# Network share with multiple users and snapshots

Tags: windows, virtualization, snapshot, windows-server-2019, smb-conf

I want to make a network share with read/write and it will be accessed by multiple computers.

Every time a new computer connects to it, they should find it in an initial state.

Every change made on the files after should be stored separately as snapshots for each User accessing it.

```
For example: 
Initial state - A 
Computer 1 - State B
Computer 2 - State C
Computer 3 - State D  etc  
If Computer 1 for example deleted some files or made bad changes, I will reset the share to state A so everything is functional again. 
Computer 2 and Computer 3 will still have access to the network share in state C and D.
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Volume Shadow Copy services, configure snapshots as often as you need and then you can restore any previous version of any file for as long back in time as you configure to do so.

There are plenty of articles on how to enable/configure VSS like [this one](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-server/how-can-i-enable-volume-shadow-copy-service-vss-snapshots-windows-server-2003).